# Comparing keys of one dictionary to another dictionary with a list of values

Tags: python, list, dictionary, list-comprehension

I have a dictionary with a list of values of varying numbers of items.
I want to compare the values of this dictionary (dict1) to the keys of another (dict2), and if they match print the key and value of the matching component of dict1, along with the value of dict2.
Both of the dictionaries are quite large, and currently this is taking way too long as you could have guessed from this basic script.

```
dict1 = {boys:[tom,jon],girls:[suzy]}

dict2 = {suzy:paper-stapler-extraordinaire,jon:paper-shredderoligist,tom:garbage-specialist}
```

output:

```
    boys \t tom \t garbage-specialist

    boys \t jon \t paper-shredderoligist  etc.....

for k,v in dict2.items():

    for key,value in dict1.items():
         if k in value[0]:
             print str(key)+"\t"+str(value[0])+"\t"+v
         if len(value)>1:
             if k in value[1]:
                 print str(key)+"\t"+str(value[0])+"\t"+v
```

Could someone suggest a more memory efficient method?  Perhaps a list comprehension?
This has not been working...
a = [k for k in dict2 if k in dict]

Comment: Use `iteritems` instead of `items` if you use Python 2.x.

Comment: Will that really make a difference as far as speed?

Comment: [`dict.items`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes#dict.items) return copy the items as list, while [`dict.iteritems`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes#dict.iteritems) return a iterator; `dict.iteritems` is more memory efficient.

Comment: Can you give an input - output example so we can help you easily?

Comment: using dict.items is still taking multiple hours.  It might be upstream in my code, but that portion is simply making the dictionaries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for dict1_key, dict1_values in dict1.iteritems():
    for dict1_value in dict1_values:
        try:
            dict2_value = dict2[dict1_value]
            print str(dict1_key) + '\t' + str(dict1_value) + '\t' + str(dict2_value)
        except KeyError:
            pass
```

That combines a few techniques to speed it up and use less memory. `iteritems` uses less memory (as others have mentioned). By using `try` and then using `dict2[dict1_value]`, you can ensure that `dict2` is only searched once, and then with the hash algorithm, which should be much faster than iterating through all the elements. For all the cases where `dict2` does not have `dict1_value` in it, the first statement under try fails, causing the `catch` block to harmlessly `pass`.

Comment: Do you mean "except" instead of "catch"?
This seems easy enough, but it never prints anything.  Is this really  conditional statement: "dict2_value = dict2[dict1_value]" ?  Even if I delete everything between try and catch, and just print dict2_value, nothing prints

Comment: @Vince Yes it should have been `except`. The first line under try is meant to be an assignment, not a conditional statement. The assignment will cause an error if `dict2` is missing a `dict1_value` key, which causes the `try` block to end and the `except` block to take over. With the change to `except`, and then entering `dict1` and `dict2` exactly as above in the question, I get three lines of output (one for each person shared between the dicts), including `girls\tsuzy\tpaper-stapler-extraordinaire`.

Comment: Hmmm.  So my dictionaries are in the exact same format as above, except with different items. This code does not work for them.  But when I use dict1 and dict2 specifically as above this works.  Does it matter how they were created? Specifically, if I created my dict in the manner  below, and then using the above code, specifying the value in such a way, it does not work.  What is the difference?
if uid not in dict2:\n
      dict2[uid] = []\n
dict2[uid].append(object)

Comment: The code was meant for dict2 to contain scalar string values. I've modified it to work with arrays by replacing `dict2_value` with `str(dict2_value)`. Before, Python would have tried to add `dict2_value` to a string and failed. I've modified the code to show errors like this when it's run by specifying `KeyError` for the error type to catch.

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for something along the lines of:

```
[(k,i,dict2[i]) for k,v in dict1.items() for i in v if i in set(dict2.keys())]
```

which returns the key,value of dict1 and value of dic2 for every value in dict1 that is a key in dict2. This can be edited to return a string etc...

This outputs:

```
[('boys', 'tom', 'garbage-specialist'),
 ('boys', 'jon', 'paper-shredderoligist'),
 ('girls', 'suzy', 'paper-stapler-extraordinaire')]
```

The set() on dict2.keys() is used to make the key look-up faster.

Comment: I keep getting TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' errors when using this

Comment: I am not sure how to troubleshoot this.  I thought it was a problem with the list of values, which was why I asked the question initially.  From what I understand this statement flows as follows:
1) for k,v in dict2[v], for k,v in dict1.items, if value is in set dict2, print whatever.  If I delete the set portion, the error is gone, but it prints an empty list. What does the set accomplish?  Thanks.

Comment: The set allows for faster look-up to see if the values are in the keys. Unfortunately the value I was originally looking up was a list and lists are un-hashable (instead you need to use a tuple). I have changed the answer to look up each individual value in the list.

Comment: Ah, perfect.  Thanks.  Good to know concerning the sets